# Getting SPList by a value from SPListTemplateType Enumeration

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am working on an older project from 2009 and there is something like

```
SPList tasksList = web.Lists["Tasks"]
```

which was used to get the `SPList`. But because of language troubles we couldn't write "Tasks".

I would like to replace "Tasks" with `107` or even better the [SPListTemplateType enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splisttemplatetype.aspx), such as

```
SPList tasksList = web.Lists[SPListTemplateType.Tasks];
```

Which does not work because `Lists` expects a `GUID` but it is unclear how to achieve that.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but might fix your problem, could you use [GetList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.getlist.aspx) to retrieve the list by URL instead of title?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [BaseTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.basetemplate) property in a LINQ query:

```
SPList tasksList = 
                 web.Lists
                    .Cast<SPList>()
                    .FirstOrDefault(list => list.BaseTemplate == SPListTemplateType.Tasks);
```